# gcc: how to enforce the presence of a parameter in a variadic_function (and possibly also the type in a known set)

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, variadic-functions, c11

I have the following function:

```c
typedef enum overrideType
{
    ovrBool,
    ovrFloat,
    ovrUint32,
} overrideType_t;

int override_New(const char name[], overrideType_t type, ...);
```

I would like the list of optional parameters to contain at least one item (even better if I could guarantee that it contains only one). Would it be possible to impose a set of allowed types as well?

Basically I would like to be able to write the following instructions:

```c
override_New("a", ovrBool, true);
override_New("b", ovrFloat, 4.0f);
override_New("c", ovrUint32, 5, "string"); /* this is tolerable but if it were possible to have a warning would be better */
```

but an error or at least a warning should be generated with the following:

```c
override_New("d", ovrFloat);
```

I'm fine with C11 with gcc extensions, attributes, using preprocessor features etc.

Comment: If you want one param, then why use variadic?

Comment: because the type is not known. In this example there are 3, but they will have to cover quite a few non-standard types as well

Comment: Why not pass a union that is able to hold all possible types of parameters? Is it mandatory to pass literals?

Comment: literals are quite a strong requirement

Comment: Have you looked into `_Generic`? This makes it possible to have just one type-generic interface that dispatches automatically at compile time according to the type of an argument.

Comment: @mastupristi *literals are quite a strong requirement*  From where?  Is it a formal requirement? Formally **requiring** specific implementation details like this is a sign of a broken and utterly misguided requirement.  It also just about literally screams, ["XY problem!"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  What actual ***problem*** is this requirement meant to solve?  This seems to me to be like the square-peg-in-a-round-hole, faked "overload" that a C++/OO-limited person crams into C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle suppose we have to replace a set of functions in a module managed by a customer, so the literals requirement is given by this. Otherwise I could have used `void *` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead your enum use standard printf formats for types. Then gcc extension `__attribute__((format(....)))` will warn you.

```
extern int override_New (const char name[], const char *fmt, ...)
    __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));


void foo()
{
    override_New("name", "%s");
}
```

```
<source>: In function 'foo':
<source>:12:28: warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' argument [-Wformat=]
   12 |     override_New("name", "%s");
      |                           ~^
      |                            |
      |                            char *
Compiler returned: 0
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q4do4r

As a bonus, it will check the type as well.

Comment: Interesting, but where did you find a hint that this is all about a `printf` like function?

Comment: @Gerhardh in the gcc documentation :)

Comment: I meant, where did you find a hint that the OP is dealing with something like `printf`. There is no hint that `"a"` are related to format specifiers. It might also be about setting named properties of different types. Also there is no support for the non-standard types

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the preprocessor (`__VA_ARGS__`), if you pass less than 3 arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum overrideType
{
    ovrBool,
    ovrFloat,
    ovrUint32,
} overrideType_t;

#define override_New(a, b, ...) override_New(a, b, __VA_ARGS__)
static int (override_New)(const char name[], overrideType_t type, ...)
{
    (void)name;
    (void)type;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    override_New("a", ovrBool, true); // Ok
    override_New("a", ovrBool);       // Error
    return 0;
}
```

Then, it will fail compiling:

```
demo.c:23:30: warning: ISO C99 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro
   23 |     override_New("a", ovrBool); // fail
      |                              ^
demo.c:12:63: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
   12 | #define override_New(a, b, ...) override_New(a, b, __VA_ARGS__)
      |                                                               ^
demo.c:23:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘override_New’
   23 |     override_New("a", ovrBool); // fail
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
demo.c:24:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘override_New’
   24 |     override_New("a", ovrBool); // fail
```

The parentheses around `(override_New)` stop the preprocessor from expanding the function definition and allows you to use the same name for the macro and the function itself.

If you want a warning instead of an error, use the `#__VA_ARGS__` `gcc` extension:

```
#define override_New(a, b, ...) override_New(a, b, #__VA_ARGS__)
```

This returns:

```
demo.c:23:30: warning: ISO C99 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro
   23 |     override_New("a", ovrBool); // fail
      |                              ^
```

But it compiles.

Anyway, is better to avoid variadic arguments at all, let the compiler do the work and use an `union` and a compound literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum overrideType
{
    ovrBool,
    ovrFloat,
    ovrUint32,
} overrideType_t;

typedef union overrideValue
{
    bool as_bool;
    float as_float;
    unsigned as_uint;
} overrideValue_t;

int override_New(const char name[], overrideType_t type, overrideValue_t value)
{
    (void)name;
    (void)type;
    (void)value;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    override_New("a", ovrBool, (overrideValue_t){true});           // Ok
    override_New("a", ovrBool, (overrideValue_t){true}, "extra");  // Error
    override_New("a", ovrBool);                                    // Error
    return 0;
}
```

This returns:

```
demo.c:30:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘override_New’
   30 |     override_New("a", ovrBool, (overrideValue_t){true}, "extra");  // Error
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
demo.c:19:6: note: declared here
   19 | int (override_New)(const char name[], overrideType_t type, overrideValue_t value)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
demo.c:31:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘override_New’
   31 |     override_New("a", ovrBool);                                    // Error
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
demo.c:19:6: note: declared here
   19 | int (override_New)(const char name[], overrideType_t type, overrideValue_t value)
      |
```